# How to make a loop rerun from onLongClick()?

Tags: android-studio, for-loop, onlongclicklistener

Here is the code. If a View has been long clicked, I want this loop to rerun by making i = 0. But the if statement after setOnLongClickListener only gets executed once in the beginning and not after the view has been long clicked.

```
final hasLongClicked[] = {false};
for(int i = 0; i < mLLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
                // tried declaring hasLongClicked[] here but no avail
                View child = mLLayout.getChildAt(i);
                child.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        //Some stuff
                        hasLongClicked[0] = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if(hasLongClicked[0])
                    i = 0;
        
            }
```

How do I do get through this? On a separate note, is this a good way to setOnLongClickListeners to all child views of a linear layout?

Help is much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making a function out of it and calling itself whenever the event has been handledas follows:

```
    private void discardEvents(LinearLayout mLLayout) {
    for(int i = 0; i < mLLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
        View child = mLLayout.getChildAt(i);
        child.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                //Do your stuff
                discardEvents(mLLayout);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Although I would like to know if this would cause any problems/ has hidden bugs.